# How to make listener on data attribute (angularJS)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, listener

I have js pie timer which is getting time from node.js and rendering pie chart.

here is code:

here I have several data-...="" attributes which is rendering the pie chart

```
<div id="myStat2" data-dimension="104" data-text="45" data-percent="0"></div>
```

here is jQuery part of what i have it is somehow listener but not best solution.

```
var time = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    time = $('#myStat2').attr('data-percent');
    $('#myStat2').empty();
    $('#myStat2').attr('data-percent', time);
    $('#myStat2').attr('data-text', parseInt(time));
    $('#myStat2').circliful({animationstep: 0});
}, 100);
```

here is the result of what is completely rendered:

[image]

here everything correct and working fine, but i suppose this is not best solution.
I thought that i can do this through angularJS but i have not idea how it is working.
Can any one offer me something better ?

Comment: That's not angularjs

Comment: I know that this is not. Just i supposed that angular can help for this issue

Comment: heyyyy why down vote what is wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A large concept of angular is to avoid these kind of DOM bindings as 2-way data binding is already provided. I assume `myStat2` is inside an angular scope so why not set a scope value in your view:

```
<div id="myStat2" data-dimension="104" data-text="{{ dataText }}" data-percent="{{ dataPercent }}"></div>
```

You can then change it directly in the $scope:

```
$scope.dataPercent = time;
$scope.dataText = parseInt(time);
```

I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve however as this code seems pointless:

```
time = $('#myStat2').attr('data-percent');
$('#myStat2').empty();
$('#myStat2').attr('data-percent', time);
```

I would recommend getting a better understand of angular and then moving this chart into some kind of directive.

Comment: Simon Staton Thank you for your response and trying to help.
Just i need something that can catch the change of the data attribute and rerender the pie

Comment: Just i need to call some function on Change time

Comment: Then you can use the ngChange directive and set a function on $scope. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange to do whatever you need to do.

Comment: Thank you you earned vote UP :) 
By the way is my question so unclear as i have earn down vote ?

Comment: @VostanAzatyan I think the problem is you were not very clear on what you were trying to achieve and did not provide any angular code.

Comment: Got it will try to be more clear. Just i have not angular Skill. I just started to learn